# Regular expression for set max width

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a regular expression

```
 /^(COM|ORG|IN)$/
```

and this is for validating that particular words,i also want to set the max width is 3 in this regular expression. can anybody please help me

Comment: It won't match anything more than 3 characters in it's present form.

Comment: ok.. then also.. can you tell what is the regular expression for set max character

Comment: `^.{3}$` would match exactly 3 characters, `^.{,3}$` would match anything _upto_ 3 characters.  You might want to refer to a manual that explains basics of regexps.

Comment: Reading a simple regex tutorial takes less time than creating a new question and the waiting for the right answers.

Comment: @Parvathiiiii: See the answer posted below

Comment: You do know that top-level domains are not limited to three characters? For example: http://info.info/

Comment: @devnull: It's should be `^.{1,3}$` otherwise javascript won't understand your Regex

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^(\w{3}|IN)$/
```

the first part matches any 3 characters and second part matches IN

I have excluded COM and ORG as they are just example of 3 characters. If you wish to allow only alphabets use

```
/^([A-Z]{3}|IN)$/
```

Here is the code:

```
var regEx = /^([A-Z]{3}|IN)$/

console.log(regEx.test("COM")) // Logs true
console.log(regEx.test("ORG")) // Logs true
console.log(regEx.test("IN")) // Logs true
console.log(regEx.test("IN1")) // Logs false
console.log(regEx.test("XYZW")) // Logs false
```